# not() method on jquery selector isn't working

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get a click event to fire if the document is clicked, unless there's a click on a div I have with a certain class name.

I've tried the following but the event won't fire.

```
$(document).not(".class").click(function(){
      //code
});

$(document).not("div.class").click(function(){
      //code
});

$("body").not(".class").click(function(){
      //code
});
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

*Update

I've tried the following

```
$(document).on("click", ":not(.class)", function(){

$('*:not(.class)',document).click(function(){

$(document).find(':not(.class)').click(function(){

$("body:not(.thisclass)").doAction();
```

But it isn't giving any distinction to the div with .class that I'm trying to exclude.  The event fires on any click on the document.

Here's the div from my html

```
<div class="pictureBox" id="pictureBox2">  <!--content--></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are attaching the click handler to `document` itself, so it will always fire (unless some other handler prevents it).

What you should do instead is use the [delegated](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) form of [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on("click", ":not(.class)", function(){
      //code
});
```

This still attaches the event handler on `document`, but this handler responds only to clicks whose source matches the `:not(.class)` selector: when the events [bubble up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to `document` jQuery invokes the handler only if the source matches the selector.

Comment: +1. Super simple way of explaining delegation/bubbling with good url resources. Correct if I'm wrong, but another way of doing (less pretty) is to make the `$(document).click()` then register `$(':not(.class)').click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation();});`. This will make the bubbling from `.class` stop on itself, not bubbling up to the document.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL that should work, except you shouldn't use not - you DO want that class in order to prevent the document click.

Comment: @jcsanyi True true. I tried edit but was already past 5mins :P But yes, the correct should be `$('.class').click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation();});`. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your selector tries to target either a `document` or `body` **without** the class `class` not a `class` element inside it, you can try something like:

```
$('*:not(.class)',document).click(function(){
```

Or:

```
$(document).find(':not(.class)').click(function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**:not selector**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

```
$("body:not(#thisid)").doAction();

$("body:not(#thisid.thisclass)").doAction();

$("body:not(.thisclass)").doAction();
```